# How to call IE or any other browser from a mfc application?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a html file and I want to open it from my mfc application, One way is shellexecute and it works, but the problem is that you have to pass iexplorer.exe location to the shellexecute as a parameter, which is usually c:\Program Files.... but what if IE is not in c:? what if windows is in another drive like d:? Is there any other way to do this? or is there any function that returns the windows drive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're overthinking it. Just call ShellExecute with just the URL:

ShellExecute(0, NULL, pszURL, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);

It will open with the default browser.

Comment: Yes but what if I specifically want to use Internet Explorer (for reasons)?

Comment: Why would you want to? What is a good reason? Even Microsoft has basically abandoned IE. Chrome is the defacto "standard" browser.  If you want to call IE, then it gets complicated. For testing purposes for yourself, just make IE the default browser and then ShellExecute with the URL as above will launch IE.

Comment: the CHtmlView class is messed up for ultra hd printing. Crops page. But IE itself prints ok. Or any other browser but I have page break issues in others. Also, Edge does not have print background setting.

Comment: I got it sorted.